# Zooming in magento 1.9 not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, magento-1.9

In my website zoom feature is not working. On hovering over an image the selected area shown is a complete image and zoom image also seems to be the same.

Is there any way I can select a small area of the original image that will be zoomed when hovering?

[image: Screen shot of zoom feature]

Answer (score 0):

i think your js are conflict to each other

Try this :

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

[Magento 1.9 - zoom and selecting options not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165913/magento-1-9-zoom-and-selecting-options-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the zoom is working because in your screenshot, the zoomed image is slightly larger than the main image.

The problem is probably either:

A) Your original image is too small. To resolve this, upload a larger image, at least 800px width preferably (and as much as 1500px width).

or:

B) Your template is not fetching the largest version of your image. You can choose which image is displayed as your zoom image and it should almost always be the largest version. This can be adjusted in your Magento admin settings or coded manually in your template (depending on what theme you're using).

For a more detailed answer, please provide the URL of your page.

Comment: Thanks, It works for me.My image resolution is around 200*200 that's why zooming not working over it.